# Filling spots in am image java where data is equal to 0

Tags: java, image, graphics

Right now I have a composite code that produces and image from recorded data. I am trying to figure out a way that I can fill the spots in the image where no data was recorded (aka where it reads 0.0) with a new color. I have been experimenting a little with Graphics, but am not finding a way that I can just will these empty spots. I would post an image if I had enough points...

But I hope you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: No, not really. What class are you using for the image? How are you filling it up exactly? What do those spots contain currently? Edit your question and add the information - relevant code would be appreciated. And you can add a link to an image, and someone will edit and embed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment suggests we really need more info.
If you use a `BufferedImage` then you can simply set a single pixel color using this method `setRGB(int x, int y, int rgb)`